# when i filter the cart the reducer function return proxy only in redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, react-functional-component

I have tried to remove the product from the cart. here the cart is an array that contains products in the object. when I try to filter the cart in reducer it returns proxy and cannot do filtering while in same thing doing in normal redux do filtering.

**reducer function**

```
const initialState = {
  products: [],
  cart: []
};

removeFromCart: (state, action) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    products: [...state.products],
    cart: [state.cart.filter((prod) => prod != action.payload)]
  };
};
```

**remove from cart button**

```
<button
  onClick={() => dispatch(removeFromCart(productData))}
  class="btn btn-danger"
  disabled={stock < 1 ? true : false}
>
  Remove from cart
</button>
```

Comment: Try to set your state instead of returning a value in your actions. state = {
    ...state,
    products: [...state.products],
    cart: [state.cart.filter((prod) => prod != action.payload)]
  };

Comment: What do you exactly mean by 'returns proxy'